# Loop all the rows in SQL server table in Azure logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am developing an Azure logic app.

**Issue:** I have a table with multiple rows. I have to retrieve all the rows and send an email for every row separately.

I am able retrieve all the rows using [action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/#get-rows-(v2)) "Get Rows", but how do I loop this rows to send an email for each row?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using GetRows, you can use Execute Query or Execute Stored Procedure to get the Result set and then use Action control to iterate over the result set and send an email then.

Here is an [`example`](http://eatcodelive.com/2016/08/08/iterate-over-the-results-of-a-azure-sql-stored-procedure-in-an-azure-logic-app/) that you can consider.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by Sajeetharan is a good solution, but since you have get the data from sql database by "Get Rows" action. I think you just need to use "For each" action to loop the "value" from "Get Rows".
[image]

My table for test in database is shown as below:
[image]

I received the three emails successfully.

Comment: Thanks Hurry for your Improved Answer. I could not select both responses as answers so i selected Sajeetharan as correct asnwer.